# Can not read data sent form mobile..Shows Unrecognized text in WireShark

Tags: wireshark

I am capturing data sent form a mobile device to my local server. I am not getting expected data in my computer so I tried WireShark to capture the data to see whats going on. The data is successfully received by WireShark but it shows Unrecognized text.

[image: wire shark screen shot]
<sub>(source: [pbrd.co](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HTBO8dg.png))</sub>

I have tired the following code to receive the data programmatically:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int port = 9090;

    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090)) {

        System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + port);

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();


            System.out.println("New client connected");


            InputStream inputStreamm = socket.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream mFileOuptutStream = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");

            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[100];

            int fByte = inputStreamm.read(fileBytes);

            int i = 0;
            while (fByte > 0) {
                mFileOuptutStream.write(fileBytes, 0, fByte);
                fByte = inputStreamm.read(fileBytes);
                i++;
            }
            mFileOuptutStream.close();

            System.out.println("New file created");

            inputStreamm.close();
            socket.close();


        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I have used following code example to send the data to the server.

```
  myhttp.sendtohttp(getrecorddate(upload_id),String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, url, ip, port));    

public byte[] getrecorddate(int ID) {

    Log.i("getrecorddate", "11111");
    GlobalRecord uploadRecord = upload_db.readDbFile(sqlite_cmd.RecordTable, ID);

    String jpg_filename = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "well%05d.jpg", ID);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int dataLen = 0;
    int recordLen = 0;

    byte strFormData[] = new byte[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        strFormData[i] = 0;

    strFormData[0] = 0x68;

    strFormData[1] = (byte) 0x99;
    strFormData[2] = (byte) 0x88;
    strFormData[3] = (byte) 0x77;
    strFormData[4] = 0x78;
    strFormData[5] = 0x01;
    strFormData[6] = 0x09;
    strFormData[7] = 0x68;
    strFormData[8] = (byte) 0x84;

    strFormData[11] = 0x50;
    strFormData[12] = 0x00;

    strFormData[21] = 0x01;

    baos.write(strFormData, 0, 28);


    byte[] jpgBuf = null;
    int jpgLen = 0;
    try {
        String fileName = GlobalFinalValues.RECORD_PATH + "Num00/SubNum000/" + jpg_filename;

        fileName = uploadRecord.String_Record[34];

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        jpgLen = fin.available();

        jpgBuf = new byte[jpgLen];
        fin.read(jpgBuf);
        fin.close();

        baos.write(jpgBuf, 0, jpgLen);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        jpgLen = 0;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (uploadRecord != null) {
        try {
            // String jpg_filename="well00001.jpg";
            byte[] jpg_name = jpg_filename.getBytes("UTF-8");
            int jpg_filelen = jpg_name.length;
            baos.write(jpg_filelen);
            baos.write(jpg_name, 0, jpg_filelen);
            baos.write(0xff);

            recordLen = jpg_filelen + 2;

            for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {

                int m;
                if (i > 7) m = i + 6;
                else m = i;
                if (i == 14) m = 35;
                String str = uploadRecord.String_Record[m];
                if (m == 35) {
                    str = uploadRecord.String_Record[35] + ";" + uploadRecord.String_Record[36];
                }//GPS
                if (str.length() > 50) str = str.substring(0, 50);
                byte[] srtbyte = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
                int len = srtbyte.length;

                baos.write(len % 256);
                if (len > 0)
                    baos.write(srtbyte, 0, len);
                baos.write(0xff);

                recordLen += len + 2;

            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    baos.write(recordLen / 256);
    baos.write(recordLen % 256);
    baos.write(0xff);
    recordLen += 3;

    baos.write(0);
    baos.write(0x16);

    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    dataLen = data.length;

    data[9] = (byte) ((dataLen - 13) % 65536 / 256);
    data[10] = (byte) ((dataLen - 13) % 65536 % 256);
    data[13] = (byte) ((dataLen - 13) / 65536);
    //data[14] = (byte) ((dataLen - 13) / 65536 % 256);

    data[dataLen - 2] = 0x00;
    for (int i = 0; i < (dataLen - 2); i++)
        data[dataLen - 2] += data[i];

    return data;
}

public boolean sendtohttp(byte strFormData[], String url) {

    boolean back = false;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        int dataLen = strFormData.length;
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(dataLen);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                ("application/xml; charset=utf-8").replaceAll("\\s", ""));

        OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

        out.write(strFormData, 0, dataLen);

        out.close();

        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        InputStream in = null;

        if (responseCode == 200) {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        } else {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream());
        }

        byte readbuf[] = new byte[100];
        int readlen = in.read(readbuf, 0, 100);

        String str = new String(readbuf, 0, readlen, "UTF-8");

        if (str.equals("succ")) {
            back = true;
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return back;

}
```

I am new to this technique would really appreciate if you can guide me.

I am expecting the data to be in text but I am getting following output:

POST /alky_gps_server/alky/send9_1 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 25925
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; AOSP on Drone Build/LMY48G)
Host: 192.168.0.75:9090
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip

h��wx  h�e8P               ���� JFIF      �� C

%# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(�� C

(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((�� ��" ��           
�� �   } !1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������        
�� �  w !1AQaq"2�B����   #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������   ? �@�~T׵9m��g&�����#��) n�9�h<�V�l5�y4�i���)1�zhM��� v�(��B���ݹ��܎�:��<� �B�G8�����Ҍm� ��1DIhj�g=iTg�"�~�&� � �b�(�Fj�A�;��
"�����P-�Ҝ�����c�Gʝ�=(sFp=���;�@��P1��N�84�3
�qN^�����_ژ���S�z�㎴�qސ�z������I��ļ� ���4���p`�ۧ�@=9(^��dNP:H"7#<P�<�t����LOAXp  �t�<����=:PTE���9xjS�8}i���s�4|٧�<�N��-E�{pi��<�G^��N�v�
!`c4(��:��g֌�ȡ{�^i ϩ�J u�{�/Niz�P5�hLsN�q�A �s@�=r��=�����2�1B�)�ڐ��x ���BM9�)�gЉ���i@�JR8��i99�9�SH���(�8�k�^GJi*G=iFH�h��M ���v� s�R q�v�.��ܯ'�GN��+c={Q���!��#ph^ �zU��H�,)��F�J^~��F����$��0s�jM��
 �M;�g<�r�"�&����H���hM���N^=��Hu��n��4���o$Ҩ �@�]g���*�F�-bM8�V�,KjKmE#&F��
��H���z~�>�����uxe����Vh���O�3�1D4f5*������6����i���U3yr�E���:���>��z���k7��?:[5�4�\��~5�j�����������Z�RFm��$��Y�}����l5��N�ÚY���.��D`y'v2A�=kE�0��+G���{a�+��=Sϱ��}�Iq8NT�o=�8��4{�������s�[�?%�4�q��<)���?��6O�\� �B�������6���g��W�z�

Comment: just noted `Accept-Encoding: gzip` have you tried gunzipping it?